# Remove params from image src

Tags: jquery, html, image, parameters

I am trying to remove all the params that are being added to my gif, as they are stopping it to animate.

This is the code of the gif: `<img src="/asset/News/6001/gif-anim.gif?thumbnail_width=2000&amp;thumbnail_height=500&amp;resize_type=CropToFit" height="500" width="2000" alt="">` but I'd like to remove all its params.

I was trying with the code below, but it's not working:

```
$('img').each(function () {
  var curSrc = $(this).attr('src');
  if ( curSrc === '/asset/News/6001/gif-anim.gif?thumbnail_width=2000&thumbnail_height=500&resize_type=CropToFit' ) {
    $(this).attr('src', '/asset/News/6001/gif-anim.gif');
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

EDITED:
By 'it's not working' I mean that is not modifying the src of the image

Comment: That code should work. Post your HTML too

Comment: And please explain what you mean by: _"it's not working"_ - What is happening, what is not happening, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your purpose is to remove complete query string from each image while iteration, then better to use [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').each(function () {
      var curSrc = $(this).attr('src');
      $(this).attr('src', curSrc.split('?')[0]);
    });
});
```

Working fiddle:-http://jsfiddle.net/gL4pv985/

Answer (score 0):

Three steps to update the source:

1. Get the current source.
2. Extract the substring from source which is before the `?`
3. Set back the source of image.

It should work for any `src` in image.

```
$('img').each(function() {
    let curSrc = $(this).attr('src');     
    let newSrc = curSrc.substr(0, curSrc.indexOf('?'));
    $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not updating the `src`. It's like the params are being added after I run this code